# Dataflow Distinct operation not scaling

Tags: performance, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, autoscaling

I have a linear pipeline with a "final" stage that outputs around 200k elements (short strings) per second.

However when I add a Distinct operation after that stage (`myPCollection.apply(Distinct.<String>create());`), the speed of the stage right before `Distinct` drops to around 80k elements processed by second.

However, I am processing a bounded collection without a maximum number of workers, so I would expect Dataflow to automatically raise the number of workers to match the workload. Not only does this not happen, when I manually start the pipeline with many workers (20+), it gets automatically downscaled to a few workers.

**How can I make Dataflow upscale the worker pool so that this Distinct operation doesn't dramatically reduce the processing rate of my pipeline ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be interesting to look at [the implementation of `Distinct`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Distinct.java#L100).

As you can see, it groups elements first, and later it picks up the first element. I've filed [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4786) to improve this behavior.

In the current implementation *all elements* are first grouped, which requires writing them to persistent storage, and later picked up. If you have any elements that occur many times (i.e. a *hot key*), you will have a bottleneck on how much data you can write out.

As a trick, you can add a DoFn that deduplicates elements *before* you write them out. Something like this:

```
class MapperDedupFn extends DoFn<String, String> {
    Set<String> seenElements;
    MapperDedupFn() {
      seenElements = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(@Element String element, OutputReceiver<String> receiver) {
      if (seenElements.contains(element)) return;

      seenElements.add(element)
      receiver.output(word);
    }
  }
}
```

You should be able to stick this before the `Distinct` function, and hopefully have better performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However after refactoring my code a little and removing the `Distinct` operation altogether, I realized that my pipeline still doesn't scale, even though some stages have a backlog of several million of items ! My pipeline is composed only of a few DoFns in a linear fashion. Think TextIO.read (fast) - some processing DoFns (fast) - a matching DoFn (slow) - TextIO.write (fast). Even though it's DoFns, the pipeline won't scale to make up for the slow DoFn. Do you have any insight that might explain this behavior ? Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. What do you mean by 'matching'? Feel free to send your question to `user@beam.apache.org`, or start a new question that I can answer on SO (link it here so I find it)

Comment: After some research I think the issue comes from one-to-many stages and have initiated a [new SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397077/right-way-to-handle-one-to-many-stages-in-dataflow). Thanks