# Right way to handle one-to-many stages in Dataflow

Tags: java, performance, one-to-many, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a (Java) batch pipeline that has follow the following pattern:

```
(FileIO)
(ExtractText > input=1 file, output=millions of lines of text)
(ProcessData)
```

The ProcessData stage contains slow parts (matching data against big whitelists) and needs to be scaled on several workers, which should not be an issue since it only contains DoFns. However it would seem that my one-to-many stage forces all the outputs to be processed only by one worker (instantiating more workers makes them all idle except one, or be downscaled if autoscaling is enabled).

Based on other stackoverflow entries, I have tried shuffling via `Reshuffle.viaRandomKey()`. This does not work because `Reshuffle` contains a `GroupByKey` which loads all the result in memory, causing OOM, even if I window it beforehand via `Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))`

Another option would be to create a CustomSource to replace the first two stages, but I find this method inadequate because 1) the documentation of custom sources is severely lacking 2) it takes more time and code to implement 3) this one-to-many issue could well be encountered in the middle of a pipeline, where I couldn't create custom sources.

**How should I handle one-to-many stages in a Dataflow pipeline ?**

Comment: In fact, that shouldn't be the case. `Reshuffle` is the recommended solution for issues of this kind. Have you found it doesn't work as intended?

Comment: @Pablo Yes. I have found that `Reshuffle` causes an OOM when lots of data is provided. I believe this to be due to the `GroupByKey` operation performed in Reshuffle.

Comment: Do you have a recent job that ran with these characteristics? How are you checking the whitelists? Reshuffle doesn't load all the data in memory, so the issue must be something different...

Comment: @Pablo Here's a job where we got an OOM in the `GroupByKey` stage of `Reshuffle`: 2018-07-18_00_00_09-18170544093139731868 . The whitelists are loaded in memory and checked via simple methods (`String.contains`, ...), but the rules take at most 1-2Mb.

Comment: I'm asking someone to take a look and give their diagnosis.

Comment: After taking a look, there clearly is too much data in one single machine. Are you able to share some of the code in ProcessData?

Comment: I created a chat room so we can avoid extended discussions in the comments https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176996/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-51397077-right-way-to-handle-one-to-many-stag